# Category specific themes?

Tags: theme-development, categories, plugin-recommendation

My client wants to implement a special appearance to each of our category pages. Kind of like child themes... she wants to shift the background image, change a few graphics, and tweak the colors according to which category the user is visiting (horror, romance, etc).

Is there a reasonable way to do this besides creating a different template for each page with imported CSS styles? Or is that really the only path to accomplish this?

**UPDATE:**
The answers below are all great. For our purposes, the easiest thing to do was to use the category specific classes provided by "body_class()" to override current styles.

Thanks!

Comment: If you came up with solution other than covered in answers, please add it as answer and not as part of question. Better for organization and voting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If changes do not require modifications to HTML markup you can accomplish that by loading conditionally additional CSS style files. See [Conditional Tags > A Category Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) and [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) in Codex.

Answer (score 0):

The bulk of your theme is made up of three files, **header.php**, **footer.php** and **style.css**.

If you want to load an alternative header, footer and/or stylesheet simply update the appropriate calls inside the category template(**category.php**) to pull in a different header/footer/stylesheet.

Example.

```
get_header();
```

Becomes.

```
get_header( 'cat' );
```

Would then include **header-cat.php** instead of **header.php**.
You can do the same with the `get_footer()` call to include a different footer file.

Using alternate header/footer files is covered on the Codex pages.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer

For the stylesheet, simply change this(in your new header file).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

For something like..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ); ?>/style2.css" />
```

Or alternatively, use `wp_enqueue_style` as suggested in the other answer.

Completely custom HTML and CSS without effecting any other kinds of pages(and no changes needed to the existing header/footer/stylesheet).